# jQuery - Bind two events to an AND operator

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is it posible to bind two events to an AND logic operator so that both has to be active for the function to be called? Say I have this:

```
foobar.bind("foo AND bar", barfunc);

function barfunc(e) {
    alert("foobar!");
}
```

So in order for `barfunc` to be called both `foo` and `bar` needs to be active. This would be really useful cause I am making a slider/seeker out of divs (Cannot use jquery UI slider) and I need it to call the function when I am both pressing down my mouse button and hovering over the div.

Comment: You may want to bind `mousemove` within `mousedown`.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I would make something similar to Ryan's answer.  You must handle each event 1 at a time.  Then you can store that result in a variable.  In each of the event handlers you can check that AND with those variables.

Comment: Please be so kind an edit your question, this definitely seems to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible using syntax like that—the events will never fire at the exact same time, one will always be after the other. That said, you could do something like the following (pseudo code based off your example):

```
var isHovering = false,
    isClicking = false;

function barfunc(e) {
    if(isHovering && isClicking){
       alert("foobar!");
    }
}

foobar.on('mousedown', function(event){

    isClicking = true;
    barFunc(event);

}).on('mouseup', function(event){

    isClicking = false;

}).on('mouseenter', function(event){

    isHovering = true;
    barFunc(event);

}).on('mouseleave', function(event){

    isHovering = false;

});
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are only triggering some behavior when both "mousedown" and "mouseenter" events triggered on the same target, the handler for "mouseenter" is likely redundant.

Comment: There's got to be an easier way. I tried that code, and it makes the whole code I have invalid, jshint says it's valid too.

Comment: If you are binding the two events to the same target you likely only need "mousedown" as your mouse has to be in the hit area (hovering) in order to click. The pseudo code I posted was to demonstrate how to track if two events were occurring on a given element at the "same" time.

Comment: The target is a slider/seeker, so I need to be able to drag the handle and move it back and forth.

Comment: Just built a slider for you using the concepts from my answer: https://jsfiddle.net/7j2k6fh6/1/. It should help get you started.

Comment: Thank you for that. I accepted your answer as fiddling a little with the code worked. Cheers!